# Implementing sign up with aws cognito in android without hosting

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, user-management

I'm trying to implement User Sign-In and Sign-Up using Amazon Cognito user pools for an Android App without any hosting.
I'm a beginner at AWS Cognito, however, I was able to create a User pool successfully and integrate Federated Identities to the user pool as well.
I read many articles and did a lot of research on this. But I was not able to find a good guide which showed me how to implement this clearly.

Hope someone could help me with this!!